# AUC depends on random splitting

Tags: logistic, classification, cross-validation, auc

I have around 1500 data samples, 10-15 features and I am training Logistic Regression for binary classification. Data is not "very clean" and I makes some imputation.

I split data into training and validation set. For splitting 80/20, based on simulations, I got AUC 66-67. For splitting 70/30 it becomes worse, like 62-64.

What could it be? What is the adequate strategy of splitting?

Comment: This is a bit of how long is a piece of string quesiton; I would strongly recommend using repeated k-fold cross validation (e.g. 20x 5-fold) and I would not trust a single split. Always look not just at the value but also at the variability of a metric.

Comment: what does 20x 5-fold cross validation mean? I am familiar with k-fold or leave-k-out cv...

Comment: Apologies for any confusion, it meant it in the context of repeated k-fold cross-validation where in this case we perform 20 times 5-fold cross validation and we then average the results.